# Blender modal timer self._handle and self._timer locals are set to None upon second execution call

Tags: python, scripting, operator

I'm working on a modal operator using the timer template provided in blender.

I'm running into an issue where variables declared locally to the operator, as they are in the template, are cleared to `None` upon the second execution of the operator - e.g. when I want to send the "stop" command.

The template declares `_timer = None` and then references it when removing it from the window manager:

```
def cancel(self, context):
    wm = context.window_manager
    wm.event_timer_remove(self._timer)
```

In my operator, the remove function no longer works because `self._timer is None`.

I've worked around it by using a `global op_timer` but I feel this should be unnecessary, unless there is something I don't know about how blender handles operators, or how python handles classes.

Thoughts?

Comment: In the template, the class property `_timer` is defined with default of None and set in the execute method.

Comment: I'm doing the same in my operator - the problem seems to be that the local reference to _timer doesn't stay set.

Comment: Suggest posting full code, as the template works fine.